# In a DiagnosticAnalyzer's action callback, how do I get the Document or Project from which the SyntaxNode was derived?

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis

I'm writing a `DiagnosticAnalyzer`, and register a `SyntaxNode` action for `SyntaxKind.Attribute`. The attribute names some other file in the project.

For example, the code being analyzed may include

`[RelatedFile("otherFileName.foo")]
    interface Whatever {...}`

In my analysis callback, I want to be able to access the contents of the related file, from the perspective of the project being analyzed. So, I need to:

1. Extract the file name from the `SyntaxNode`. I can do this.
2. Get an object describing the document containing the code being analyzed. *I don't know how to do this.*
3. Get an object describing the project containing the code being analyzed. *I don't know how to do this.*
4. Find out if the project contains a document by the specified name. I can do this.
5. Open and parse or update the contents of that file. I think I can do this.

I get stuck on steps (2) and (3). (Yes, I may not strictly need to do step 2, but I'd still like to know how.)

From the `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext` parameter, I can get the `Workspace` object, and from that the `Solution` object, and from that a collection of `Project` objects. But I don't see a way to relate the particular `SyntaxNode` back to the `Project` or `Document` from which it came.

Any ideas about how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it:

```
Workspace workspace = ...;
SyntaxNode node = ...;
Document document = workspace.Solution.GetDocument(node.SyntaxTree);
Project project = document.Project;
```

I don't know why I didn't see that earlier.
Edit: I now know why I didn't see it earlier. Getting ahold of the `Workspace` requires using a non-public property of `AnalyzerOptions`.

You can get the `Workspace` from a `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext` via...

```
SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context = ...;
AnalyzerOptions options = context.Options;
Workspace workspace = (Workspace)
    (options.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("Workspace").GetValue(options));
```

It's not pretty, but it works. I wish there were a better way.

Comment: Jim, could you explain how you get the Workspace from the SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext?

Comment: Thanks Jim. I don't know if it is a better way, but you can also get the workspace [as described by Josh Varty](https://joshvarty.com/2014/09/12/learn-roslyn-now-part-6-working-with-workspaces/). If you are not in a VSPackage, you can call GetService using the ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell. This might require references which you strictly should not use in a code analysis. In a code fix (but not a code analysis) you can import the workspace as an MEF component.